# How to remove child layer cocos2d

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have small problem with removing a child Layer. I am not sure how to remove the layer correctly.

Here is my code sample

```
-(void)GoMoveFirst
{
    //
    //====HERE IS COMBOBOX START

    CCMenuItemImage *lvl1 = newButton(@"retry1", 200, 590, self, @selector(onRetry));
    CCMenuItemImage *lvl2 = newButton(@"retry1", 500, 590, self, @selector(onRetry)); //onHighScore:
    CCMenuItemImage *lvl3 = newButton(@"retry1", 800, 590, self, @selector(onRetry));
    CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:lvl1, lvl2,lvl3, nil];
    menu.position = ccp(0, 0);
    [GameLayer addChild:menu z:103];
}
```

After I press one of this buttons, I need it to be removed.
All stuff is going here:

```
-(void)onRetry
{
    //
//HERE i need remove menu Child.
//

    [m_sGo runAction:[CCSequence actions:actionMove, [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(GoMoveSecond)], nil]];
}
```

One idea was try make it invisible, but I do not think this would be a suitable option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store a reference to the child you want to remove (i.e a pointer to it in your `@interface`).

I'm fairly sure you can assign a `CCNode` a tag too, so it might be worth looking into that. You can then remove the node based on the tag you assign to it. Both are accessed with `removeChild` from the parent node.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove a subclass of the CCSprite (in this case CCMenuItemImage) then you use the removeChild method from the CCLayer class. In this case:

```
-(void)onRetry{

[self removeChild:lvl1];//This would remove the CCMenuItemImage object called lvl1.


    [m_sGo runAction:[CCSequence actions:actionMove, [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(GoMoveSecond)], nil]];
}
```

Comment: lvl1 wouldn't exist in the scope of onRetry

Comment: @davbryn You are right. I meant to use tags. Forgot to add that part in